# DfPlayer Mini not working when using three LR44 batteries

Tags: power-supply, arduino, batteries, audio, attiny

I'm working on a small project that plays audio. This project uses an ATtiny85 and a DFPlayer Mini as well as some other small components to make the whole thing work. I've tested the circuit using an Arduino Uno's 5 V pin and everything seems to work nicely, however, when I use three LR44 batteries with a Schottky diode for protection, all the other stuff seems to work except the DFPlayer Mini: All it does is play this weird buzzing sound. I'm not sure why this behavior is occurring and I'm wondering why the batteries are causing this issue since they should be supplying enough power for the whole circuit.

Here's the circuit (ignore the DFPlayer Mini's VCC pin, I forgot to draw the connection):

[image]

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUwGAuzZwi8) a video of the problem in action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LR44 cells (or the [equivalent A76](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/a76z-.pdf)) are small watch batteries that have very limited current capability. They're designed to operate devices in the µA to mA range (the datasheet indicates that the capacity was measured with a 6.8 kΩ load, which would be about 220 µA). Putting three in series gives you 4.5 V, but the *current* delivery is still limited.

An audio amplifier, even driving a small speaker, will need more current than that. Try using AAA or AA cells, for example.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this. Are there any alternatives instead of using AAA or AA cells (my project is small in size, as such using these would take up a majority of the space needed for other components and such)? Many thanks! : )

Comment: Most coin cells of any type have a fairly high internal resistance (which just means not capable of higher currents). You might consider a small (100-200 mAh) lithium polymer battery which will be around 3.6 V nominal, but you'll have to check whether all of your components work with that voltage. Alternately, a 2S (two cells in series) would yield 7.2 V and you'd need to add appropriate voltage regulators, etc.

Comment: I'll check out the LiPo batteries and see if there exists a relatively perfect size, thank you! : )